# URLRewrite "Redirect" rule works, but "Rewrite" rule fails (404)

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, proxy

I have following rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="First Rule" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^Tracking/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.example.com/" />
</rule>
```

This failes, calling http://www.myserver.com/Tracking/123 returns a 404.

However, if I change the action type into Redirect, the rule suddenly works fine, performing a redirect:

```
<rule name="First Rule" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^Tracking/(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/" />
</rule>
```

But I need a rewrite rule, as I need a reverse proxy to an internal server.

I'm working on a Windows 2008R2 Server (IIS 7.5), have "IIS URL Rewrite Module 2" installed,...

What is wrong with the Rewrite rule ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you're setting up a reverse proxy to an internal server. If a URL Rewrite destination is outside of the server performing the rewrite, you will need to install Application Request Routing to enable proxy capabilities. After installing Application Request Routing (ARR), you'll need to go to its proxy settings and check the Enable Proxy feature. A full blog on this setup can be found [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing). If this has already been performed, I would recommend using Failed Request Tracing on both the reverse proxy and destination server (if the destination server is IIS) in order to better understand where the HTTP 404 response is coming from.

Comment: Thank you! In my case the URL Rewrite rules were correct, and ARR was installed, but ARR did not show up in IIS. Uninstalling and reinstalling ARR fixed it (http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing)